# display different under IE6 and other browers

Tags: html, css

i know  IE6 is dead,but in china, there are lots of people still using it. so expect someone can do me a favor about this problem.

this is the page.the even line's background color is not the same length, under IE6, which is shorter

the display under IE6. (http://run.xxmn.com/ie6.jpg). the bgcolor displays different  from other browers.

the display under IE7,FF,CHROME  (http://run.xxmn.com/ie7.jpg). it displays ok.
how to make it under IE6 displays the same result as other browers?

ps:the problem is solved. thanks all the guys.

Comment: I don't see any bg difference in your two sample images? The only diff I can see is different font rendering, which every browser does differently anyways.

Comment: not the font, the even line's background color is not the same  length, under IE, which is shorter.

Comment: Why not use <table> to display tabular. <table> is indeed not wise for using to design a website, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use them for their purpose.

Another note that is a bit out of subject, is that you shouldn't use the following class "`*`" specially for displaying inheritable properties like `font-size`.

Define a `body` class and put them in it.

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in IE6 is probably due to negative margins on the `views-field-title` class (though I don't have IE6 installed to check).

You don't actually need negative margins to achieve the effect you want. So suggest removing them like this:

- Remove `margin-left: -4px;` from `#left_cplist .cplist-bg .view-content .views-field-title`
- Remove `margin-left: 5px;` form `#left_cplist .cplist-bg .views-row`

Comment: i have deleted them,but under IE6,the werid display is still that.